# OData Expression ampersand character for filter throw error

Tags: c#, asp.net, extjs, odata

I am using fluent NHibernate. While filtering for data like 'Soup & Caesar' i.e. for string including 'ampersand' sign throw an error of - Unterminated string started at 12.
I tried to research in it and found that ODataExpression.cs file uses below code for filter due to which it threw error.

```
private void ParseQueryString(string queryString)
    {
        if (queryString.Length == 0)
            return;

        var queryElements = queryString.Split('&');

        for (int i = 0; i < queryElements.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] elementParts = queryElements[i].Split(new[] { '=' }, 2);

            string key = HttpUtil.UriDecode(elementParts[0]);
            string value = elementParts.Length == 2 ? HttpUtil.UriDecode(elementParts[1]) : "";

            ProcessQueryStringPart(key, value);
        }
    }
```

I wanted to know if there is any way I can avoid this. Validating textfield will not be proper solution for me as I have gone far in my project and changing everything will be problematic.

Please Note - I am using EXTJS which sends data in encoded form so has to something at code behind side.

Thanks.

Comment: when the string literal 'Soup & Caesar' comes in as part of a http query string, then it would have to be url-escaped, because what the above function does is to tokenize the http query string, where the & is the separator. What does your full query string look like? Apart from that, I think that data from a text field had better be POSTed, not GETted, so you would be reading it from ASP.NET's form collection, not query string.

(the current scenario looks like the classic sql injection attack vulnerability).

Comment: ExtJS does not automatically send all data in encoded form. Please post the relevant client-side parts of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to UriEncode your QueryString before it is submitted, so it would look something like this:

```
http://www.example.com?text=Soup%20%26%20Caesar
```

Consider using POST and reading the textbox content from ASP.NET's Request.Form collection to overcome possible other implications (length limitations, line breaks)

Comment: This is not working. I am using EXTJS which already  send data in encoded form.

Comment: can you inspect the actual query string in the debugger to confirm it is properly uri-encoded? portions of client-side code and runtime values will be helpful too.
are you in an Ext.Ajax.Request call? if so, encoding is not done automatically, try Ext.urlEncode({text:'Soup & Caesar'})